# How to hide text when checkbox is clicked

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, onclick

I've created a checkbox and a small section of text bookmarked as approve to attempt to hide when a checkbox is clicked, but it doesn't seem to be working. I feel that I mus be over-simplifying it for it not to be working, so am I missing anything (still very new to VBA). Here's what I've got:

```
Private Sub checkbox1_Click()
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi. Shouldnt be  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden=true ?

Comment: I've added that and it still does't help

Comment: FWIW f you want to show/hide the text, using ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden = checkbox1.Value (or Not checkbox1.Value, as appropriate) should work. It works here, assuming that your checkbox1 is an ActiveX control in the document surface. Is the event code definitely running (e.g. you could put Msgbox "We're in!" in there to check). Your nearby question was about doing much the same thing with content controls. If you have the choice - I would stick to CCs and avoid using ActiveX controls in the document.

Comment: Jordy, could you please use the [edit] link to update your question with the current code. Then: 1) What does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean? Nothing is getting hidden? Is there an error? 2) If you go to the Insert/Bookmarks dialog box, select the bookmark name and click "Go to" does it *select text* or does the cursor just "blink"?